# What is the difference between ground state, excited state and transition dipole moment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, molecules, dipole-moment

I need to find a transition dipole moment of Rhodamine 6G molecule, however they provide ground state and excited state dipole moment. Are they similar or can I somehow obtain transition dipole moment from the given ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition dipole moment depends on which *transition* you are looking at. It gives you the probability of state $a$ transitioning into state $b$, and will look something like $\langle b | ...|a\rangle$, where the dots are to be replaced by the specific interaction-inducing term you are dealing with (magnetic moment, electric dipole moment, etc.).

So you should find transition dipole moments between any one state and any other state. Some of these transitions are forbidden by selection rules.